# Mass-replacing strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following table of tweets

```
id  tweet
------------------------------------------------------
1   alcoa inc stock analysis
2   bullrider has added alcoa inc to portfolio
3   caterpillar annual results
4   more at http://bit.ly/d3423 on caterpillar
5   making apple inc profits
```

I would like to replace company names with a specified label, as follows:

```
id  tweet
------------------------------------------------------
1   {COMPANY|AA} stock analysis
2   bullrider has added {COMPANY|AA} to portfolio
3   {COMPANY|CAT} annual results
4   more at http://bit.ly/d3423 on {COMPANY|CAT}
5   making {COMPANY|AAPL} profits
```

I now have the following query:

```
UPDATE
  tweets
SET
  tweet = REPLACE(tweet, 'alcoa inc', '{COMPANY|AA}')
WHERE
  tweet LIKE '% alcoa inc %'
OR
  tweet LIKE 'alcoa inc %'
OR
  tweet LIKE '% alcoa inc'
```

I have two questions, though:

1. Isn't there a better way to catch all possible "alcoa inc" instances?
2. Is it possible in SQL to write a sort of an array for multiple replacements (in SQL, so not from within PHP). Here. I mean defining in SQL something like `array("alcoa inc" => "{COMPANY|AA}", "caterpillar" => "{COMPANY|CAT}", "apple inc" => "{COMPANY{AAPL}")` and loop through it in SQL for a mass-replace.

Your help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Why don't you just use `tweet LIKE '%alcoa inc%'`?

Comment: I would guess it's so it doesn't match, for example, `balcoa inc`.

Comment: @mellamokb - You are right, didn't think of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try storing the list of tickers and companies in a table and use a query like this:

```
select
    case
        when c.ticker is not null then
            replace(t.tweet, c.name,
                    concat('{COMPANY|',c.ticker,'}'))
        else t.tweet
    end as tweet
from
    tweets t
left join
    company c
        on
            t.tweet like concat('% ', c.name, ' %')
        or
            t.tweet like concat(c.name, ' %')
        or
            t.tweet like concat('% ', c.name)
group by
    t.id
```

The only downside being this solution won't handle the case where two companies' names appear in the same tweet. Only one of them will get replaced.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8da9d/2

---

**Edit**: As pointed out by `@Mario`, it's possible that the matching will cause an incorrect replacement if there are multiple instances in the same string.  For instance, using the string `I have a redapple from apple` with the replacement `apple` will result in the string `I have a red{COMPANY|AAPL} from {COMPANY|AAPL}` because the second `apple` triggers a `LIKE` match, then the `REPLACE` replaces every match.  I have an updated query that handles this situation as well by reading the matching strings out of a table as well:

```
select
    case
        when p.ticker is not null then
            replace(t.tweet,
                replace(p.replacestr, '{0}', p.name),
                replace(p.replacestr, '{0}', concat('{COMPANY|',p.ticker,'}')))
        else t.tweet
    end as tweet
from
    tweets t
left join
    (select * from pattern,company) p
        on t.tweet like replace(p.pattern, '{0}', p.name);
group by
    t.id
```

Where `Pattern` is a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Pattern
    (pattern varchar(50), replacestr varchar(50));

INSERT INTO Pattern
    (pattern, replacestr)
VALUES
    ('% {0} %', ' {0} '),
    ('{0} %', '{0} '),
    ('% {0}', ' {0}');
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c71d4/3

Comment: But as I understand, this could be solved by running the query twice, no?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there a better way to catch all possible "alcoa inc" instances?

REGEX(Reqular Expression) search. Take a look a the official [mysql REGEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) documentation for further information.

> Is it possible in SQL to write a sort of an array for multiple
>   replacements (in SQL, so not from within PHP). Here. I mean defining
>   in SQL something like array("alcoa inc" => "{COMPANY|AA}",
>   "caterpillar" => "{COMPANY|CAT}", "apple inc" => "{COMPANY{AAPL}") and
>   loop through it in SQL for a mass-replace.

Yes, you can create a specific table to store the key->value dictionary and then get value from it, so fo example :

```
 table : dictionary
+----------+-----------------------+---------------+
| name     | pattern               | replacement   |
+----------+-----------------------+---------------+
|alcoa inc | [[:space:]]+alcoa inc |{COMPANY|AA}   |
|apple inc | apple inc.*           |{COMPANY{AAPL} |
```

And you can update with a query like the following, for example :

```
UPDATE tweets SET tweets = REPLACE(tweet, 'alcoa inc', '{COMPANY|AA}') 
WHERE  tweet RLIKE (SELECT pattern FROM dictionary WHERE name = 'alcoa inc');
```

*It is only an example to illustrate a possible way, you have to tune it for your requirements and specific context.*

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is with a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateTweetsWithCompany
    @CompanyName varchar(255) = 'alcoa inc',
    @ReplaceValue varchar(255) = '{COMPANY|AA}'
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE
      tweets
    SET
      tweet = REPLACE(tweet, @CompanyName, @ReplaceValue)
    WHERE
      tweet LIKE '% ' + @CompanyName + ' %'
    OR
      tweet LIKE @CompanyName + ' %'
    OR
      tweet LIKE '% ' + @CompanyName
END
```

And then call it, somewhat like this:

```
EXEC UpdateTweetsWithCompany 'alcoa inc', '{COMPANY|AA}'
```

Comment: Though, the `REPLACE` would still replace a string like `'balcoa inc'` to `'b{COMPANY|AA}'`.

Comment: It shouldn't because of the filters provided in `WHERE..LIKE`

Comment: @mellamokb a `tweet` could be `"I had a redapple from apple"` and the `REPLACE` would change all occurrences. E,g: If we'd change `"apple"` to `"{COMPANY|AA}"` it would end up as: `"I had a red{COMPANY|AA} from {COMPANY|AA}"`. Even though the `WHERE` clause would find " apple".

Comment: Ah. In that case it's because the *second* `apple` triggers the match via the third LIKE statement, and then the replace actually affects both.  I see now.